# how eigen determine to use blas or not in runtime

Tags: android, eigen, blas

I am using eigen in my project. surprisingly, also find that qualcomm make a lib, [QSML](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-math-libraries) for snapdragon process, even a drop-in replacement for BLAS. I open that like : `#add_definitions(-DEIGEN_USE_BLAS)` in cmakelist. it's simple and work! roughly 2x speed up!

however, QSML would not run for other socs, no mtk, samsung... and crash in runtime. is it possible to configure building for qualcomm and mtk and others in cmake, or gradle build? or is it possible for an android to know what soc is running on and switch different .so? or how eigen with blas runs on every android phone?

Comment: If android support dynamic libraries and that QSML is a dynamic library, then you could start your app with loading either QSML or the Eigen's BLAS lib (that you have to compile yourself with `make blas` from Eigen's source code).

Comment: @ggael I never paid attention to the `./blas` directory. Is there a benchmark shown somewhere comparing it to e.g. Intel's MKL?

Comment: For single threaded products, there is at max a 5% difference. For multithreading the difference becomes more important as the number of cores increases.